# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm getting the following error (or something similar with different extensions involved)
on all 3 @Html... code lines:

> Error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,string,object)
>   and 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,string,
>   object)

Does anyone know how I can go about fixing this? I was wondering if I might have duplicate assembly references somewhere but I'm not too sure. This issue is causing quite a plethora of errors in other files too. All of them complain about the same problem, and I'm not too sure what modifications or updates I need to add to it to get rid of those bugs.

I recently updated our local Inventory application system from Telerik MVC2 to MVC3
so I'm thinking that might be why these errors were created.

```
<div id="main" class="wrapper">
 <div class="clearfix toolbar" >
   <label>&nbsp; Approvals</label> <br />
   <div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Current Approvals", "Approvals", "Assets", new {view="Current" }, null)
 @Html.ActionLink("Approval Log", "Approvals", "Assets", new { view = "Log" }, null)
   </div>
</div>
@Html.Partial("Transfers_Partial_Grid", Model)
```

Comment: It certainly looks like a duplicate assembly, but it is impossible for anyone to tell based on what you have posted.

Comment: I'm thinking that as well. Is there any other additional information I can provide that could help solve this issue?

Comment: Could be a namespace issue, hard to tell without seeing you controllers. You could try doing a search on one of the actions and see where it comes up?